# Python Code syntax not working in databricks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, azure-databricks

I am migrating my python code from Jupiter notebook to databricks notebook. But lots of things don't work as it is.

The below code works properly in Jupyter notebook but does not work in databricks:

```
# Replace Periods with Month Name:    
replacements = {
   'FISCAL_PERIOD_NBR': {
      r'(Per01)': 'Feb',
      r'(Per02)': 'Mar',
      r'(Per03)': 'Apr',
      r'(Per04)': 'May',
      r'(Per05)': 'Jun',
      }
}

df_input.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

I don't see any errors either but the column "FISCAL_PERIOD_NBR" gets deleted post this statement. I am not sure what changes are required while migrating the code from jupyter notebook to databricks but there is a 1500 line code which I have to debug line by line. Any support is appreciated.

Comment: are you using pandas or pyspark? did you check pandas versions ?

Comment: I am using pandas 0.19.2